# SharpDevelop - how to embed, compile exe file with dll's assemblies?

Tags: c#, compact-framework, sharpdevelop, windows-embedded-compact

I am developing a net compact framework project in sharpdevelop 3.2.
It works great but there have to be dlls like firebird net provider and other assemblies i use, inside folder with exe when i run it.
How to embed all this dll's into exe, to have it embedded all in one exe file and not need to copy paste them separetely into folder where i run exe from?

Comment: or do i have to just use ilmerge?

Answer (score 0):

The method I use most often for this sort of thing is to add the assemblies to the EXE as resources, then add a handler for the [`AssemblyResolve`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx) event to unpack the assembly from resource into memory and load from there.

The nice part of using `AssemblyResolve` is that you can override the resource-bound assemblies with an actual assembly on disk if necessary, since it won't call `AssemblyResolve` until it fails to find the assembly through normal means.  If you prefer to force it to always load the resource, hook [`AssemblyLoad`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyload.aspx) instead.

You can also compress the resources to reduce bloat, saving on total deployed bytes.